# I don't get notifications when I comment on pages I "Like". Why is that?

Tags: facebook, notifications, comments, facebook-like

Let's say I "Like" a specific page on Facebook and make a comment about it. I don't get notifications if someone either "Likes" my comment or writes a comment after mine. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could anyone intentionally have you reported on facebook (spam, hate speech, etc.) to cause it?.  That "was" a feature of Facebook´s social plugin. Can't find an explanation on facebook documentation about why it was removed (by the end of 2012). I used to receive notifications for every someone else's reply or "like" to my comments or posts on a news web page, no matter if others were friends or not.  Now, I only get notifications on replies.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's ever been a feature, has it?
As far as I know, you don't get notifications for subsequent comments to content you've commented on on pages (exception being when one of your friends likes your comment)

Comment: At one time it was, I remember I got notifications and emails for each one. At times, it was annoying but it good to see the back and forth banter. Now, it's totally done away with?

Answer (score 1):

If you like a fan page, you won’t get notifications like you used to. This is because Facebook has pushed the page owners to "promote their posts" with money. In other words, the fan page owner must now *pay* Facebook a certain amount of money to reach a guaranteed amount of its followers. Without paying, the post will only reach about 10 percent of the people that liked the page.

Answer (score 1):

When you comment on a post, click on the dropbox in the upper right corner of the post its self(Where Edit/Delete Post usually is), then click follow post. You will be notified of any comments made on that post.